# I need to find a word in a sentence and then capture to the control characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm setting up a python script to search through thousands of words in a list. (one list in in the hundreds of thousands)

```py
words = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sec', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', ...]
```

I figure joining the words into a single string will make it easier to search through them.

```py
word_str = '|Lorem|ipsum|dolor|sec|amet|consectetur|adipisecing|elit|'
```

Cool, so now I can search for a term.

```py
import re

re.findall(r'(sec)', word_str)

>> ['sec', 'sec', 'sec']
```

I should clarify, the search terms are defined by “the customer” and sometimes are regex expressions themselves. I have created a UI that allows the customer to input a comma separate list of search terms [strings]. Terms are completely open-ended and does include regex.

```py
search_terms = ['search', 'terms', 'can', 'be', 'anything']
```

In the past, I have just combined the term list into a single pattern string and smashed that against the compiled `word_str`.

```py
term_str = '(' + [i.strip() for i in search_terms].join('|') + ')'
re.findall(term_str, word_str)
```

The problem with this approach is I end up having to iterate through the list multiple times to return the whole matching string as well as the term used to find said string.

1. Create `term_str` and `word_str`
2. Check if any item from `term_str` exists in `word_str`
3. If match, iterate through `words` and check if any item in `term_str` matches.
4. If match, iterate through `search_terms` and check if the term matches the specific word.
5. If match, save the result to a `dict`
6. Repeat.

I feel there *has* to be a better way. Especially since there are hundreds of search terms and thousands of words.

Now, the part I can't wrap my head around; I need to return the match to the word boundaries. e.g. |<-- *con* **sec** *tetur* -->|
 and |<-- *adipi* **sec** *ing* -->|

```py
re.findall(r'<magical expression here>', word_str)

>> ['sec', 'consectetur', 'adipisecing']
```

It's embarrassing how many different permutations I have tried.

- `(?<=[|])(.+?(sec).+?)(?=[|])`
- `(?!\|).*?(sec).*?(?!\|)`
- `\|.*?(sec).*?\|`

To name a few. Each captures either **way** too much or not enough.

I believe it spawns from an almost complete misunderstanding of how the regular expression machine works. It would be amazing if someone out there could help me out here.

Answer (score 3):

You originally had a list. A lookup using `in` in the list using a list-comprehension is a way *better* approach than creating string out of it and then using regex:

```
words = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sec', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipisecing', 'elit']

print([x for x in words if 'sec' in x])
# ['sec', 'consectetur', 'adipisecing']
```

Comment: I agree this would be a much better approach however, I don’t control the search terms. They are “customer” inputs, sometimes regex statements themselves. I’ll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: @kdougan, Nevermind the search item. Take "customer" input to variable and substitute this variable in place of `'sec'` in above code. I don't understand your second point. Does customer give you regex expression as input? In that case, it's pointless writing our own expression.

Comment: My apologies. Further edits to the question have been made. I hope it helps. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @kdougan, just to be clear. You have a list of search items. And you need to search with each of these search items in `words` list and return every word that contain it?

Comment: A [long] list of search terms. An [even longer] list of search words. Need to return/find whole words which matches any of the [potentially] partial search terms. Using regex because the search terms [may] contain regular expressions.